# Yahoo outgoing mail server setting for the Javamail API?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, yahoo-mail

I tried these setting for the sending mail from my application. It's work fine and after some days . It's not working.

```
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
props.setProperty("mail.host", "android.smtp.mail.yahoo.com"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");  
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Error what I got is :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: android.smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465, response: -1
```

**Edit 1:** *********

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");  If I used this than I got the EOF xception
```

I got the properties from here :

[yahoo mail setting](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MOBILE&locale=en_US&id=SLN3696)

Comment: Are you using a mobile device?  Perhaps you have poor connectivity in some areas?  Do you have better luck if you just use "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"?

Comment: I also tried this mailhost but could not get helped from this . @BillShannon

Comment: I assume that means "yes", you are using a mobile device.  Sounds like you just have poor connectivity which is why it works sometimes and not others.

Comment: @BillShannon : ok ,  thanks for the sugesstion